# .NET MySQL: Print column names and values

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I would like to print/debug the name of all columns and their values.

I tried something like this:

```
    Dim nCmd As MySqlCommand
    nCmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM payinout WHERE inout_searcher=" & Apo(u), g_CnWebDB)

    Dim r As MySqlDataReader
    r = nCmd.ExecuteReader()
    bExists = r.HasRows

        For Each f As Field In r.fields
            Debug.Print(f.name & ": " & f.value)
        Next
```

... but since these members are missing, I guess I am not on the right track.
Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a standard loop using FieldCount and GetName method, but call Read before trying to read anything from the MySqlDataReader

```
    r.Read()
    For x = 0 To r.FieldCount - 1
        Debug.Print(r.GetName(x) & ": " & r(x).ToString)
    Next
```

Please, take note, the query used is open to Sql Injection. If this is only test code then it doesn't matter, but in production use parameterized queries.